# Functions in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I have a function

```
function(a, b)
    print(a+b)
```

How can I translate this to tikz language so that it requires an "a" and a "b".

```
hello = 1
bye = 2

function(hello, bye)
```

the output from this would be 3

Comment: Is `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called `add`. You can wrap macros around it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand{\myaddandprint}[2]{\pgfmathparse{add(#1,#2)}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand{\myparseandprint}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={hello=1;bye=2;}}
\pgfmathparse{add(hello,bye)}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult

or \pgfmathparse{hello+bye}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult

\myaddandprint{hello}{bye}

\myparseandprint{hello+bye}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have something that is more reminiscent of the python language, maybe `tikzmath` is what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{integer \x, \y, \z;
\x = 1;
\y = 2;
let \z=\x+\y; 
print {$x=\x$, $y=\y$, $z=x+y=\x+\y=\z$};}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have expandable functions, you can use `xfp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\begingroup\def\x{1}\def\y{2}\fpeval{\x+\y}\endgroup
\end{document}
```

As long as you are careful in what you are doing, you can mix it with pgf, but you need to remember that it strips the units.

Comment: This is almost right. I would want to use the format ```function(a, b)``` and then the function would operate on the two inputs

```function(1, 2)``` would print 3
```function(4, 7)``` would print 11
etc...

Comment: I got it dude
.
```
,tex
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={yeet(\a,\b)=\a+\b;}]
\draw (0,0)--(3,3);
\draw (0,3)--({yeet(2,1)},{yeet(5,3)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @OllyEatough As I said, this function exists and is called `add`. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)--(3,3); 
  \draw (0,3)--({add(2,1)},{add(5,3)}); 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: I know but that isn't the only thing I want to do with my function. I just wanted to see if I can make a function that operates on two inputs given in the parentheses 

function(A, B)

With this function I can do practically anything I want with A and B respectively or irrespecitvely

Comment: @OllyEatough It's ok to post partial info, compared to the real problem in your heart, as a question. But if that question is well solved, then it is recommended to first express thanks to whom helps you. Also if the real problem is still unsolved, follow-up new questions are welcome.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I have now ticked Scrodinger's answer. He's helped me with a lot of questions of the same topic so be assured I have thanked him. Thank you again Schrodinger's cat.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={yeet(\a,\b)=\a+\b;}]
\draw (0,0)--(3,3);
\draw (0,3)--({yeet(2,1)},{yeet(5,3)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is perfect for what I want to do. In this script I am drawing a line from (0,0)--(3,3) and another line from (0,3)--(3,8) because 2+1=3 and 5+3=8

Comment: If you replace `yeet` by `add`, you get the same result.

Comment: If I wanted to do \a+\b*\a then I couldn't do that with add

Comment: Well, this is what I suspected when I made [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/535679/nested-arrays-and-functions#comment1353166_535679). As predicted, if you post a vague question, only you can answer it because you know what the question really is. So others waste their time to learn from your self-answer what you really wanted to do.

Comment: I'm sorry. At least now if someone searches for something similar to what I wanted I give a straight forward answer. Please do not get this confused with me saying that your answer wasn't straight forward. I am just stating that this question wasn't a complete waste of time because others might learn from it!

Comment: This question exists in 500 flavors. Others tend to learn more from well-posed clear questions. You question asks about an "output" but in reality you want to wrap a function around coordinates parsed by Ti*k*Z.